# Is there a way to prevent overwriting a file in a docker image?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a base Docker image with a server on it that will then get built on top of to host specific applications. Is there a way to prevent certain files from being overwritten in downstream images.

For example, let's say I had an Apache Tomcat image and I don't want someone else with an app to override the `web.xml` file by running `ADD myapp/web.xml $CATALINA_HOME/conf` within their Dockerfile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn’t possible.  (A typical Dockerfile does most of its work as a root user, and if it doesn’t, it can trivially `USER root` if it really wants to overwrite that file.)  This also doesn’t seem like a big deal for the case you describe since Docker images are usually single-purpose, and if some specific app running on top of your Tomcat image really wants to reconfigure the app server, Docker’s isolation means it’s not going to affect anything else.

If you *really* want to you can put a copy of the file in a safe place and copy it back in during an entrypoint script, but if I were a downstream developer and I ran across this behavior I’d probably be a little frustrated (this definitely violates the principle of least surprise).

Comment: Yeah I get that it's a bit of a weird use case, but the idea is to encourage as little change as possible downstream to limit debugging (not my idea but I get where it's coming from). I also think it's particularly useless in an application running in something like Tomcat since you can just specify application specific configurations in something like a WEB-INF. Thanks for giving a clearer understanding of the feasibility of it though.

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately, whoever bases their image on yours, has full control to overwrite any configuration or file they want to. Docker is not built to prevent it.

That said, it is possible to help this problem, if you simply want to prevent accidental overwrites.

I would chain ENTRYPOINT to be your own script that in turn starts your server. But before that, it validates integrity of a bunch of components, e.g. server.xml ports and connectors, web.xml etc. It can be as sophisticated as generating a validation signature and submitting it for your cluster validator. E.g. if you run in Kubernetes, there can be an orchestrator that lists and verifies all running containers and it could validate such signatures and stop everything not up to the required standards.

I.e. your problem should be elevated to a runtime environment, which you have a task to secure, instead of the image level, where you should allow as much flexibility as possible, to enable future development.